# Installing GCC 4.7.1 on OS X

Tags: macos, shell, gcc, installation, gnu

I am trying to install `GCC` 4.7.1 on my Mac because I want to update the `LLVM GCC` 4.2 given in XCode.

I have downloaded `GCC` 4.7.1 and I've placed the `gcc-4.7.1` folder in `~/Downloads`, then I followed the instructions given here: http://gcc.gnu.org/install/ and I wrote

```
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
~/Downloads/gcc-4.7.1/configure --with-gmp=/usr/local/include --with-mpfr=/usr/local/include --with-mpc=/usr/local/include
```

and the configuration does show problems.

Then I wrote

```
make
```

and it all goes well until I am given this message

```
rm -f stage_current
Comparing stages 2 and 3
warning: gcc/cc1-checksum.o differs
warning: gcc/cc1obj-checksum.o differs
warning: gcc/cc1plus-checksum.o differs
  Bootstrap comparison failure!
gcc/intl.o differs
make[2]: *** [compare] Error 1
make[1]: *** [stage3-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Then the `make check` gives me this message

```
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: ./fixincludes: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [check-fixincludes] Error 1
make: *** [do-check] Error 2
```

And the `make install` this messagge

```
/bin/sh /Users/fpiro07/Downloads/gcc-4.7.1/mkinstalldirs /usr/local /usr/local
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: ./fixincludes: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [install-fixincludes] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

How can I fix these problems and have my `GCC` 4.7.1 installed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install [MacPorts](http://macports.org) and run:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
$ sudo port install gcc47
```

It will take care of correctly configuring and installing gcc (4.7.2 at the time of writing) and all dependencies.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have downloaded the .pkg file and installed it via double-click. Afterwards I entered 'sudo port selfupdate' into my terminal an it says 'sudo: port: command not found'

Comment: Okay so you need to restart the terminal after the installation of macports! But still it doesn't work because when I enter g++ --version I see that I'm still at version 4.2.1 ... !

Comment: You need to check that `/opt/local/bin` is in the `$PATH`.  Check out the macports docs for details.