# Why is the c++ standard library not working?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, terminal, standard-library

I've been trying to get my program that I downloaded from my schools server to run offline on my mac. I tried updating GCC by following tutorials and for some reason the tutorials didn't work even though I was using the commands given.

Now when I compile.. I get an error saying that  is not found.. I don't get it. I've updated Xcode.. followed tons of tutorials.. and I still can't get the thing to run!

Why is it saying that random is not found, causing a fatal error?

Thanks

### Error:

```
DungeonLevel.h:6:10: fatal error: 'random' file not found
```

### "Since this is a coding site, I need to provide code because I probably forgot to include a header file..."

```
#ifndef _DungeonLevel_included_
#define _DungeonLevel_included_

#include "Tile.h"
#include <vector>
#include <random>

class Player;

class DungeonLevel {
public:
    DungeonLevel(int iWidth, int iHeight, std::mt19937 & randomGen);
    ~DungeonLevel(void);

    void dump();
    char at(int x, int y);

    Creature * removeCreature(Creature * creatureToRemove);

    void moveCreature(Creature * creatureToMove, char dir);
    void placeInGame(Creature * creatureToPlace, std::mt19937 & randomGen);
    void placeInGame(Creature & creatureToPlace, std::mt19937 & randomGen);
    Tile & returnTile(int x,int y);
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> m_vvTiles; //Tile was char

};

#endif
```

### Here's my makefile:

```
OBJECTS = Ammunition.o Armor.o Consumable.o Creature.o Entity.o Gold.o Item.o parser.o Potion.o Scroll.o Weapon.o XMLSerializable.o CreatureFactory.o DungeonLevel.o Player.o Tile.o ItemFactory.o
HEADERS = Ammunition.h Armor.h Consumable.h Creature.h Entity.h Gold.h Item.h parser.h Potion.h Scroll.h Weapon.h XMLSerializable.h CreatureFactory.h DungeonLevel.h Player.h Tile.h ItemFactory.h

all: Jhack

%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    clang++ -c $< -o $@ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++

Jhack: $(OBJECTS) main.o
    clang++ -o Jhack $^ -stdlib=libc++

clean:
    rm -f *.o Jhack

run: Jhack
    ./Jhack
```

Comment: Lol I obviously didn't forget an includes.. And the same code works fine via SSH.. But I'll post code anyways

Comment: It would be nice if we knew which file it reports as missing.

Comment: There are 83 files. It's included in several of them. The first time it encounters it... Fatal error

Comment: I think it would help a lot to see the _full_, _actual_ error that you are encountering.

Comment: Lol I literally said exactly what the error said. But okay, I'll copy and paste it.

Comment: `<random>` was introduced in C++11. Either you're using an old version of GCC or you don't have C++11 mode enabled. Or your installation or file system is corrupt.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious that's possible. I tried the MacPorts tutorials and the commands it showed to run weren't working. I can't seem to get it to update the newer GCC.

Comment: What do you get when you type `which g++` and `g++ --version` in the console?

Comment: @juanchopanza I can't get it to update. I tried following tutorials and the commands they tell me to enter don't work. It's at 4.2.1 currently :/

Comment: Usually, macports installs go to `/opt/local` or something. You could try there, or try with an explicit version, e.g `g++4.7` or something. I am not on a mac OS at the moment so I can't check the exact details, but you get the general idea: mac needs to keep its system versions of GCC stable, but you can install any number of other versions. You just have to figure out how to pick those up.

Comment: Uhhh how do I do that? I see them in finder when I search for the library files.

Comment: I don't know much about Mac, but does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153725/installing-gcc-4-7-1-on-os-x Can your question perhaps even be regarded as a duplicate of that question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple's gcc is really outdated. Try to build using clang and libc++ instead of gcc and libstdc++. Compile flags: `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`, link flag: `-stdlib=libc++`. Use clang++ instead of g++.
**Edit**: note that you need to install latest command line tools for this to work.
Open XCode. Go to "Xcode" -> "Preferences..." -> "Downloads" tab. Select "Command Line Tools" and install them. If it says that it is installed - check for updates by clicking on "Check and Install Now" button.
After that type `clang++ --version` in terminal and you should see something like next:

```
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

**Edit 2**: if that didn't help and you still have an outdated version of compiler. Try to use `xcrun clang++` instead of `clang++` in your makefile. That will use xcode toolchain.

Comment: Yeah can't get that to work either. Ugh this is so frustrating. Is there not a way to get it to use the new version that's installed somewhere in my files?

Comment: You need to update XCode, install command line tools from XCode, replace g++ with clang++ in your makefile, add compiler and linker flags I've told above to the appropriate places in makefile, `make clean` and `make`

Comment: Looks like you didn't add `-stdlib=libc++` to compile flags

Comment: I've never used flags before. Sorry I'm probably making you just as frustrated with my lack of knowledge =/

Comment: Replace this line in your makefile: `g++ -c $< -o $@ -std=c++0x` with this one: `clang++ -c $< -o $@ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`; this one: `g++ -o Jhack $^` with this one: `clang++ -o Jhack $^ -stdlib=libc++`

Comment: clang++ -c Creature.cpp -o Creature.o -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
error: invalid value 'c++11' in '-std=c++11'
make: *** [Creature.o] Error 1

Comment: what `clang++ --version` tells you? I've just tested it on my mac - no errors.

Comment: Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: WTF? What version of OS X are you using and what version of XCode?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should update command line tools.

Comment: You probs don't believe me, but it says it's up to date.

Comment: And what about button "Check and Install Now"? And I suggest you to enable checkbox "Check for and install updates automatically" to avoid such problems in future.

Comment: No, simulators wouldn't help you. Lets try something else. Run `xcrun -find clang++` in terminal. What would it say to you?

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++

Comment: ok. Now replace all entries of `clang++` in your makefile with `xcrun clang++`

Comment: That means that it finally started to compile. You can ignore warnings (but I usually prefer to fix them). Do you have any errors now?

Comment: You are welcome. clang has many warnings flags and as far as I know most of them are enabled by default. And off course you can ask author of the code about the warnings ;)

Comment: OK cool. I did a make clean and now its saying No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: `make clean` will just remove all object files and a binary. To build it again you need to run `make` again. Or this what you are getting when you are running `make` again? If so check if there is a Makefile out there in current directory.

Comment: Yeah that's what I got from make again. I reverted though. Somehow the makefile must have gotten deleted. Anyways thanks a ton man!