# Problems compiling a Linux centric project on Mac OS

Tags: c++, linux, macos, gcc, clang

I am trying to compile "[Entropy Broker](http://www.vanheusden.com/entropybroker/)" on Mac OS (10.8.5).  It's a C++ project and it compiles fine on Ubuntu Linux.

The errors are:
kernel_prng_io.cpp:13:23: error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory
kernel_prng_io.cpp:15:26: error: linux/random.h: No such file or directory

Changing the includes in those two files to "sys/types.h" and "sys/random.h" resolves the file not found errors but creates other errors: " error: 'RNDGETENTCNT' was not declared in this scope" which I take to mean that those are not the correct versions of those include files.

I've found a similar question here: [Why is the c++ standard library not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229297/why-is-the-c-standard-library-not-working) but none of the suggestions there work for me... and I have a later version of CLANG anyway.

I've got the Xcode command line tools installed and updated. GCC & G++ are symlinked to CLANG and the version is Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76). I have Homebrew and I've installed the latest GCC but I am not sure how to alter the Entropy Broker Makefile to make sure it uses GCC instead of CLANG.

If anyone has any tips, I'd really appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: These include files are Linux-specific. You won't find them on Mac OS X. `sys/random.h` is not an equivalent of `linux/random.h` and `sys/types.h` is not an equivalent of `sys/types`. You need to actually port Linux-specific code to either Mac OS X or to some kind of POSIX standard, not mechanically replace include file names. The question you have found has absolutely nothing to do with this issue. It's an OS issue, not a compiler issue.

Comment: @n.m. You should promote this to an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have to admit I'm a bit surprised, as the file I'm trying to compile is described as being platform independent and able to be used on BSD and Mac OS.