# Make fails with: fatal error: 'random/uniform.h' file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, clang

I am having an import issue with `<random/uniform.h>`.

The issue is because random was introduced in c++11 ([Why is the c++ standard library not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229297/why-is-the-c-standard-library-not-working)). I can specify support for c++11 with -std=c++11 or -std=c++x0, but it won't work with g++. I tried using clang, but I am not sure if I have the required min clang version (4.2).

```
    clang++ --version
```

gives

```
    Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
    Thread model: posix
```

When I check Xcode for updates, there are none.

Comment: Isn't `gcc` just a symlink to `clang`?

Comment: Are you sure there is a header in c++11 std named <random/uniform.h>?

Comment: Yeah looks to me like it should be `#include <random>`.

Comment: What @trojanfoe said, minus the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Hahah. What semi-colon :D

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm trying to avoid changing their code that *supposedly* works. If I just include random, then I get "error: use of undeclared identifier 'uniformRandGen'". Maybe they aren't even referencing random, but a different library that I don't have?

Comment: @Sean - the C++ standard provides the header `<random>`. It does not provide a header `<random/uniform.h>`. It also does not define an identifier `uniformRangGen`. So whatever it is that you're talking about, it's not standard C++, but there's no hint in your question of what you're trying to do or where these names are coming from.